# Selector in table tr and data-type

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table `#sortable-categories`
And in some tr's I have `data-order="something"` (1,2,3..).

I want to select them all. Tried everything but the syntax is incorrect

```
for(i = 1;i<=count_ordered;i++){
        $("#sortable-categories tr [data-order="+i+"]").hide();
    }
```

Can you please help me with that :)

Comment: Try removing the space between the tr and the [data-order] selector.

Answer (score 2):

If `data-order` attribute is an attribute of `<tr>` elements then:

```
$("#sortable-categories tr[data-order]").hide();
```

It will hide all `<tr>` elements within your table, that have `data-order` attribute.

**NOTE:** for `.hide()` method the order doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on my comment, your problem is probably the space between the TR and the [:

```
for(i = 1;i<=count_ordered;i++){
    $("#sortable-categories tr[data-order="+i+"]").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very stupud... the tr and [data-order must be without space.
$("#sortable-categories tr[data-order="+i+"]").hide();

Answer (score 0):

The format is `htmlelement[attribute="value"]` like so.

I've used single quotes for jQuery just to make the attribute selector a bit clearer:

```
for(i = 1; i <= count_ordered; i++) {
    $('#sortable-categories tr[data-order="'+i+'"]').hide();
}
```

As you can see the single quotes escape the string so you can concatenate your variable, whereas the double quotes will be part of the string used by jQuery.

If you want to find attributes that contain a value and is not an exact match the format is:

```
htmlelement[attribute*="value"]
```